# How to put a multiple file selection into an array to output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, file

I have a file upload application which once a file has been selected status will appear saying the name of the file. What I am having an issue with is adjusting the case where there are more than one files being uploaded.

Originally, a count would be given - if you upload three files, '3' would appear. I am attempting to adjust this so that the three file names are displayed. I took the code getting the single file name to show `fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();` and tried adding it to the condition is more than one:

```
if (this.files && this.files.length > 1) {
    //fileName = (this.getAttribute('data-multiple-caption') || '').replace('{count}', this.files.length);
    //fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    console.log('Here is it ' + fileName);
    //$('#fileName').html(fileName);
 }
```

What I get is a single file name outputted. I can't figure out how to get the file name list in an array to output.

Does anyone see what I need to adjust?

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputfile');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  var label = input.nextElementSibling,
    labelVal = label.innerHTML;
  if (this.files && this.files.length > 1) {
    //fileName = (this.getAttribute('data-multiple-caption') || '').replace('{count}', this.files.length);
    //fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    console.log('Here is it ' + fileName);
    //$('#fileName').html(fileName);
  } else {
    fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    console.log("I am running");
  }
  if (fileName) {
    //label.querySelector('span').innerHTML = fileName;
    //label.querySelector('span').innerHTML = fileName;
    $('#fileName').html(fileName);
    $('#fileStatus').text('File attached!');
  } else {
    label.innerHTML = labelVal;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="uploadedFile" class="inputfile" id="uploadedFileTest" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple>
<label for="uploadedFileTest" id="uploadFileTest"><img class="total-center" src=""></label>
<p id="fileStatus"></p>
<p id="fileName"></p>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. But, it doesn't really look like you're adding a new element to show the new file.It looks like you keep overwriting the same element #fileName

Comment: You'll probably need an unorderedlist and for each file add a line item with two p elements.

Comment: @JD333 How would I do that though?

Comment: I'll post an answer in a  sec.. But with jquery, find the element with the class filename. Then using jquery create another p tag called filename-2. Append the newly add file name to it. Keep a **count** so that you can dynamically add a class called filename-index where index is your current **count**.